# Where can I find piano sheet music for Sekaiichi Hatsukoi's OST 1 track 10?

Tags: music, sekai-ichi-hatsukoi

I have looked on Josh's anime sheet music and Musescore; I haven't been able to find the piano sheets for this song.
[Here is the song](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nRvzJ5ckOLw).

Comment: There is a transcription of the song that is [available for purchase](http://www.dojinongaku.com/contents/goods_detail.php?goid=16035).